# Html.ActionLink syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

The code below is supposed to print out the names of the genres created in the Model as a hyperlink to them in another page. What is the purpose of `new { genre = genre.Name }`? We already have the for loop executing code for each genre, where the code gives the genre name and location of the View. So what is the point of that last parameter?

```
<ul>
 @foreach (var genre in Model)
 {
     <li>@Html.ActionLink(genre.Name, "Browse", new { genre = genre.Name })</li>
 }
</ul>
```

Comment: genre is probably a parameter on the action that's being called and this is how you add query string parameters to your hyperlink

Comment: oh, yes you are right. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter is the route values object:

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx):

> **routeValues**
>
> Type: System.Object An object that contains the parameters
> for a route. The parameters are retrieved through reflection by
> examining the properties of the object. The object is typically
> created by using object initializer syntax.

The link will be generated with a query string that contains the input object values.

For example (the link text is the first argument, `genre.Name` in your example):

```
/Controller/Browse?genre=value
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Ofiris' answer. Here's info from W3School:

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_htmlhelpers.asp

Henry